# Some kind of type alias : An empty derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, alias, downcast

What I would like to know is :

- Is this snippet portable ?
- If not, why ?

---

```
struct GenericBase{
};

struct MyObject : public GenericBase{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct MyAlias : public MyObject{
    //supposed to have exactly the same layout as MyObject (?)
};

struct MyImpl : public MyObject{
    virtual void method() { cout << "method implementation \n"; }
    //note that MyImpl inherit MyObject, but we cast it to MyAlias
};

void test_alias(){
    MyImpl m;
    GenericBase* ptr = &m;
    MyAlias* new_ptr = static_cast<MyAlias*>(ptr); //here is the cast
    new_ptr->method();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I cant't use RTTI, nor templates

Comment: Looks weird :/ ... Use templates: [Curiosly Reccuring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Thanks but I can't use template

Comment: _'Thanks but I can't use template'_ Can you elaborate why please??

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve with this? Why do you need to cast to `MyAlias*`?

Comment: I guess that if I had written `using MyAlias = MyObject` every would work just fine. But :
1) You can't forward declare a using directive.
2) For syntactic purpose, what I tried to achieve is : 
`using alias<T1> = ClassA;`
`using alias<T2> = AnotherClassB;`
Which I though I could do with inheritance and template specialization

Comment: @Julien__: The syntax for that is `template <class T1> using alias = ClassA<T1>` in C++11. Not sure which compilers support it. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias.

Comment: @Julien__ _'I can't use template'_ and _'... and template specialization ...'_ I don't get it, isn't that a bit contradictory? As soon I spot the `static_cast<>` in your code, that's a clear indicator for me, CRTP is a possible solution for your use case, and you should forget about the runtime polymorphism (which won't work properly here anyways).

Comment: Well, I can't see how to use CRTP here ?

Comment: @Julien__ Have a look at my answer, hopes this clarifies a bit ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer:** This is not portable.

```
struct MyAlias : public MyObject{
    //supposed to have exactly the same layout as MyObject (?)
};
```

This comment is wrong : the size of MyAlias is implementation dependent and is not specified by the standard (it depends, for example, on the alignment requirements of the target architecture: the compiler may add padding bits in the derived object, or on how method dispatching is implemented etc..)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this snippet portable ?

No, this is not portable. Reasoning as said in [@quantdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510483/quantdev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148659/1413395).

What I would do is omitting `GenericBase` and usage of runtime polymorphism (`virtual`) at all:

```
template<typename Derived>
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject() : theRealInstance(static_cast<Derived*>(this)) {
        // Check the available interface as soon an instance is created
        void (Derived::*op1)(void) = &Derived::methodImpl;
        (void)op1;
    }
    void method() { 
        theRealInstance->methodImpl(); 
    }

private:
    Derived* theRealInstance;
};
```

---

```
struct MyImpl : public MyObject<MyImpl> {
    void methodImpl() { std::cout << "method implementation" << std::endl; }
};

struct MyWrongImpl : public MyObject<MyWrongImpl> {
};
```

---

```
void test_alias(){
    MyImpl m;
    m.method();

    // Uncomment to see the compile time error
    // MyWrongImpl w;
    // w.method();
}
```

Check this **[working sample](http://ideone.com/4PcuqO)**.

You could even require `method()` implementing a pure abstract interface, but in general that's not necessary

```
struct GenericBase {
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class MyObject : public GenericBase {
public:
    virtual void method() { 
        theRealInstance->methodImpl(); 
    }

    // Rest as above
};
```

You can find a bit more about this topic, and how to do static interface checks in this GitHub repository: [StaticInterfaces](https://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces).

Comment: This is very interesting ! I might use it a lot, thanks for those details ! (+1)

Comment: Although it doesn't answer my original question : How do you introduce the 
          `MyAlias* alias_ptr = &m; //in your function test_alias()` without `class MyAlias` knowing anything about `class MyImpl`

Comment: @Julien__ BTW: The way I proposed to check an interface (layout as you call it) in the constructor, isn't restricted to provide compile time checks for plain class member functions (as pure `virtual` inheritance provides), but even for static class member functions, class members as public variables, available typedefs, constants, etc. ...